# I want to repeat 5 in both sub-arrays? I mean the ending number of previous sub-array should be starting number of next?

Tags: ios, arraylist, swift4, slice

Starting with a large [String] and a given subarray size, what is the best way I could go about splitting up this array into smaller arrays? (The last array will be smaller than the given subarray size).

Concrete example: Split up ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"] with max split size 4

The code would produce [["1","2","3","4"],["4","5","6","7"],["7","8","9"]]

Comment: Can you show your attempt?  It looks pretty trivial, simply iterate over the input array and produce the output arrays with some simple logic.

Comment: Don't  repeat questions, you already have an answer in the previous one.